# ffmpeg +libx264 iPhone -> 'avcodec_encode_video' return always 0 . please advice

Tags: iphone, encoding, ffmpeg, h.264, pts

`av_register_all();`

```
        AVCodec *codec;
        AVCodecContext *c= NULL;
        int  out_size, size, outbuf_size;
        //FILE *f;
        uint8_t *outbuf;

        printf("Video encoding\n");

        /* find the mpeg video encoder */
        codec =avcodec_find_encoder(CODEC_ID_H264);//avcodec_find_encoder_by_name("libx264"); //avcodec_find_encoder(CODEC_ID_H264);//CODEC_ID_H264);
        NSLog(@"codec = %i",codec);
        if (!codec) {
            fprintf(stderr, "codec not found\n");
            exit(1);
        }   
c= avcodec_alloc_context();

        /* put sample parameters */
        c->bit_rate = 400000;
        c->bit_rate_tolerance = 10;
        c->me_method = 2;
        /* resolution must be a multiple of two */
        c->width = 352;//width;//352;
        c->height = 288;//height;//288;
        /* frames per second */
        c->time_base= (AVRational){1,25};
        c->gop_size = 10; /* emit one intra frame every ten frames */
        //c->max_b_frames=1;
        c->pix_fmt = PIX_FMT_YUV420P;

        c ->me_range = 16;
        c ->max_qdiff = 4;
        c ->qmin = 10;
        c ->qmax = 51;
        c ->qcompress = 0.6f;
```

'avcodec_encode_video'  is always 0 .

I guess that because 'non-strictly-monotonic PTS' warning, do you konw same situation?

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this problem? I am having the same issue, it looks like it is something to do with the PTS value.

Answer (score 0):

For me also it returns 0 always. But encodes fine. I dont think there is an issue if it returns 0. In the avcodec.h, you can see this

"On error a negative value is returned, on success zero or the number
 * of bytes used from the output buffer."